# What is the Java equivalent of Trim('/') in C#

Tags: java, c#

Consider this code:

```
string xx = "/test/file2/".Trim('/');
Console.WriteLine(xx);
Console.Read();
```

This code returns `test/file2`. What is an efficient way to do this in Java?

Comment: I'd suggest you do away with the C# comparison, and just ask how to trim a character from either end of the String. People looking at the c# tag probably don't care about this question (unless they also happen to look at the Java tag), and people looking at the java tag probably don't care that c# has this ability, they just care on what it is you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do the same in Java:

```
 String xx = "/test/file2/".replaceAll("(^/*|/*$)", "");
```

This uses a regex that matches multiple / from the beginning or multiple / at the end and replaces them with void.